# .ashx handler doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, handler, ashx

I have plenty of handlers in my project, but now none of them work, they stopped work after I created a virtual directory in my application pool (godaddy servers).

I had to create a virtual directory because I had some configurations to make in the `web.config` file, (full trust), and for that I needed to have the project in a virtual directory, and it solved.

What can I do to solve this problem:

```
%@ WebHandler Language="C#" CodeBehind="login.ashx.cs" 
   Class=".handlers.login" %>
```

Error:

> Could not create type 'ProjectSeller.com.handlers.login'.

Comment: Care to share your code for login.ashx.cs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple, i had to place the handlers in an App_Code folder inside the virtual directory.